# two-quadrant frequency mixers without transistors?

Tags: voltage, transistors, operational-amplifier, analog, mixer

I understand that four-quadrant frequency mixers without transistors are difficult to implement. But what about two-quadrant? Would implementing mixers without transistors still be difficult? Would these mixers suffer from "threshold voltage" (if using diodes, maybe?) and one has to increase the physical size of the mixer?

Comment: You have a very similar previous question - did you not understand the answer and decided to repost with a bit of a disguise? If you understand the answer given then please consider accepting that answer and explaining why this new question is different: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/189962/a-circuit-that-does-multiplication-of-two-signals-when-some-scaling-down-is-ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the best performing mixers just use diodes and accurate transformers. ([Double balanced mixer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_mixer)) to do four quadrant mixing.

They do have loss and need a lot of local oscillator drive but they are low noise so the overall noise figure can be pretty good.

Mini-Circuits is one of the most well known manufacturers ([Mini-Circuits](http://www.minicircuits.com/products/Mixers.shtml).